# Bind WindowsFormHost with Iconf.net ProcessBytes method

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, iconfsdk

Currently I am binding a windows form with video stream bytes like given code:

```
 var opened = CheckOpened(peerId);

                if (opened != null)
                {
                    ((ClientForm)opened).icc.ProcessBytes(bytes);

                }
```

**CheckOpened function**

```
private Form CheckOpened(string name)
        {
            FormCollection fc = System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms;

            foreach (Form frm in fc)
            {
                if (frm.Text == name)
                {
                    return frm;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

How can I bind WindowsFormHost  with this?. This will bind every time a specific button is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

`WindowsFormsHost` is just a holder for windows forms content. It doesn't expose any dependency properties  that the form can access (required for binding).

In general, its for legacy support only, and doesn't fit well with the MVVM pattern.